# How to install the full TexLive on Centos 7

Tags: texlive, sphinx, centos, capt-of

I am trying to make some documentation using `Sphinx`, and packages are continually missing. I have tried installing the full version, however, I must have failed since, despite being over 450 MB, I am still missing packages.

I did this

```
sudo yum install texlive-*
```

However, when I run `make latexpdf`, I get

```
! LaTeX Error: File `capt-of.sty' not found.
```

I am using Centos 7. Apparently for [Centos 8](https://installati.one/centos/8/texlive-capt-of/), this should be done

`sudo yum -y install texlive-capt-of`

Unfortunately, it does nothing for me:

```
user$ sudo yum -y install texlive-capt-of
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.its.dal.ca
 * centos-sclo-rh: mirror.its.dal.ca
 * centos-sclo-sclo: mirror.its.dal.ca
 * epel: iad.mirror.rackspace.com
 * extras: centos.mirror.vexxhost.com
 * updates: mirror.its.dal.ca
No package texlive-capt-of available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Comment: You might consider using the [tl-install script](https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html) from TUG rather than using the rpm packages, which will always be out of date for an older version of a distro like CentOS. (Be warned though it's a lot bigger than 450mb to install everything.)

Answer (score 1):

For me, I did not install with yum, using command like this to install latex:

```
wget https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz --no-check-certificate
zcat < install-tl-unx.tar.gz | tar xf -
cd install-tl-*
yum install perl-Digest-MD5 -y
perl ./install-tl --no-interaction
```

follow this link https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html from the comments.